# Algorithm for distributing/aligning multi selected shapes vertically or horizontally at equal distance

Tags: algorithm

I need to write logic to distribute or align multi selected shapes horizontally or vertically with equal spaces between the selected shapes/objects.

In PowerPoint 2010 we have option "Distribute horizonatlly" and "Distribute vertically". [Please refer this link for clarification](https://www.indezine.com/products/powerpoint/learn/shapes/distribute-shape-in-ppt2010.html) Similar functionality I have to implement in my application.

Is there any algorithm already available to meet my requirement?

Comment: The problem is underdefined; please be more precise

Comment: From looking at it I think Power Point is just enclosing each shape in a minimum bounding rectangle. Then for distributing horizontally, it fixes the leftmost and rightmost bounding box and distributes the other boxes equidistant in between.

Comment: Thanks SaiBot. Is there any algorithm already available for implementing this feature effectively?

Comment: @User890:  algorithm?  This is straightforward algebra.  Where are you having trouble?

Comment: @Prune.I am not having any trouble in implementation.I just want to know whether there is any predefined algorithm available for this case.

Answer (score 1):

**Note: Here I only convert @SaiBot comment to steps**

1. Calculate the min rectangle border for each shape (this depends on how you implement your shapes).*You can have help in this step by posting another question with the tag of your programming language.*.
2. Total Shapes Width = the sum of all shapes widths.
3. Remaining White Width = The width of your page - Total Shapes Width
4. Space (the space between each shape) = Remaining White Width / (n - 1). Where n is the number of shapes.
5. First shape position is Zero (i.e. at the left most point).
6. Each shape (except the first) position equals the sum of all shapes positioned before it + "Space" * the number of these shapes.

   if the shapes indexes (i) start from 0 to n, the shape width is Wi, the shape start position is Pi, and Space is the calculated white space between each shape then...

   Space = Sum[from 0 to n] (Wi) / (n - 1)

   Pi = Sum[from 0 to i] (Wi) + n * Space